# Selecting element its value in coffeescript

Tags: dom, coffeescript

I want to select an element based on its name and get its value.

I currently have:

```
document.getElementsByName 'employee_search_first_name'[0].value
```

which compiles to:

```
document.getElementsByName('employee_search_first_name'[0].value)
```

But I need:

```
document.getElementsByName('employee_search_first_name')[0].value
```

To make my situation a bit clearer:

- I do not have access to jQuery or any framework for that matter.
- I do not want to store the element in a variable as I need more than just this one.

What would be the valid coffeescript to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parentheses are optional in CoffeeScript, unless they're not. This is a case where you need the parentheses to disambiguate:

```
document.getElementsByName('employee_search_first_name')[0].value
```

Yes, this is valid CoffeeScript.